# Additional Autonumber in an SQL table that has an identity

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I get an additional auto-number in my SQL table.
I already have an IDENTITY column, but i need an additional column that also auto-increments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a set of [**ranking functions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) that you can use for this. For instanse, you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function like so:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY somefield) rownum
FROM table;
```

Comment: Would i be able to use this in a Stored Proc?

Comment: @Josefvz You can use these set of functions anywhere. They are built in functions in the Transact SQL Language, like any other funciton you can use it anywhere. In a stored procedure, udf, view,etc ..

Answer (score 1):

If you have two auto-incrementing columns then they must always differ by a constant, so there can't be any value in doing this right? If you really want it to be a column then you can make it a computed column based on the value of the auto-incrementing column,

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this,

Assuming you have a table with columnName `ColA`, and this is what you want to increment,

```
INSERT INTO tableName (colA, colB)
SELECT  COALESCE((SELECT MAX(colA) + 1 FROM tableName),1) as ColA, 
        'colBValue' AS colB
FROM tableName
```